# Account access e-mail change

Tags: support, login

How do I change my e-mail address? There seems to be no way to access my account when my old e-mail address has been deleted. Upon changing my internet provider and using my Gmail account I cannot log on to the site.

Answer (score 7):

You probably need to contact Stack exchange directly, though you may find the answer elsewhere through that link. This one might help you https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials it details adding additional credentials to your account, if you remember your username and password to your old account, you may be able to log in there, add your gmail adddress and then remove your old one. If you don't remember you password, you probably need to contact stack exchange directly and see if they have a different way. There is a contact link at the bottom of each page, use this to get ahold of someone who can help.